# onDrawFrame is not called after requestRender has been called

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have made a View implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer and implements the onDrawFrame function.
I requestRender like this:

```
@Override
    public void postInvalidate()
    {
        super.postInvalidate();
        requestRender();
    }
```

this View is added by another View,and it works(is draws what i want to).but i want to use the 
GLSurfaceView.Renderer in another View,so i remove it in the first view and added it to the second view like this

```
m_oMapView = FirstView.getMapView();
        FirstView.remove();//oo
        SecondView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        SecondView.addView(m_oMapView,new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        m_oMapView.refreshDrawableState();
        m_oMapView.findViewWithTag("map").bringToFront();
```

after i added it to the secondView ,the requestRender seems not work,i force to called ,but the ondrawFrame function never excute.Is there any reason that ondrawFrame is not called after requestRender?

Comment: I found it works int android4.0,but int 2.2 or 2.3 not works.